# How to control EOL and leading spaces in Mako?

Tags: python, template-engine, mako

With the following, I would like to control the EOL:

```
<%!
    import sqlite3
    def data():
        return [(1,2,3,4,5), (1,2,3,4,5)]
%>
/**
 * Header file
 */
#define foo bar

% for row in data():
    { \
    % for col in row:
        ${col}, \
    % endfor
    }
% endfor
```

The goal is to print:

```
{1,2,3,4,5},
{1,2,3,4,5}
```

I've tried to do something like:

```
% for row in data():
    {<%for i, col in enumerate(row):%>${','*bool(i)}${col}<%endfor%>},
% endfor
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about defining some short functions for the output like so:

```
<%!
    def data():
        return [(1,2,3,4,5), (1,2,3,4,5)]

    join_data = lambda dat, delim: delim.join(join_row(row) for row in dat)
    join_row = lambda row:'{%s}' % ','.join(str(i) for i in row)
%>
```

Then

```
${join_data(data(), ',\n')}
```

will output

```
{1,2,3,4,5},
{1,2,3,4,5}
```

or if you want tabbing you could do

```
    ${join_data(data(), ',\n\t')}
```

which will yield

```
    {1,2,3,4,5},
    {1,2,3,4,5}
```